# Configuring ethernet network in order to test client-server app written in Java

Tags: macos, java, ethernet

I have connected the two computers using an Ethernet crossover cable. But I just can't seem to make them work.

I know it certainly isn't some physical-connection-related issue, I mean it's just plugging one end of the cable into an Ethernet port and the other into the other; so it must have something to do with configuring Ubuntu's and Mac OS X's respective Network Managers properly..... I just quite can't put my finger on how to do that?

If I run the client that I have coded on the Mac and the server on Ubuntu, both consoles on both computers just hang, if I do it the other way around Ubuntu keeps on hanging and this time I get a SocketException: PermissionsDenied on my mac's console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify the network is working

- check each PCs IP-address using `ifconfig -a`
- from each computer use `ping` with the other's IP-address

In your client program, replace `192.168.0.0` with the IP-address of the computer acting as the server.